# Как выполнить JS в python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Нужно выполнить js из python и получить данные, которые выдаст js после выполнения. Видел что есть `PyV8`, но он только для `python2`. Есть ли что-то похожее для `python3`, работающее под всеми OC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622385/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-from-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модуль Naked делает именно это. `pip install Naked` (или установите из исходного кода, если хотите) и импортируйте функции оболочки библиотеки следующим образом:

```python
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

response = muterun_js('file.js')
if response.exitcode == 0:
  print(response.stdout)
else:
  sys.stderr.write(response.stderr)
```

При таком содержимом `file.js`

```
var x = 10;
x = 10 - 5;
console.log(x);
function greet() {
     console.log("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

вывод будет

> "5\nHello World!\n''

<sub>перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623079/14227417) от участника [@manan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3242010/manan)</sub>

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но Naked выдаёт 1 при запуске js, то есть код выполняется неверно и ничего не выводится -_- Вот ссылка со всеми подробностями: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889051/why-does-naked-execute-the-code-incorrectly